# Binding DataGridComboBoxColumn to Object

Tags: c#, wpf, combobox, datagrid, datagridcomboboxcolumn

I'm trying to bind a Combobox to an object within a datagrid with little success.

Object.cs:

```
public class Object {

public static IEnumerable<string> Colors => new List<string> {"Red", "Green", "Blue"}

}

public string Color {
get => color;
set => color = value;
}

private string Color;
```

My ViewModel contains a collection of these models, which I'll call `Objects`.

XAML file:

```
<DataGrid Name="DataGrid" ItemsSource={Binding Objects}" Style={StaticResource DataGridStyle}">
    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridComboBoxColumn Header="Test" SelectedValueBinding="{Binding Color, StringFormat=F3, Mode=TwoWay}" ItemsSource="{Binding Colors}"/>
    <DataGrid.Columns/>
<DataGrid/>
```

Anybody know what I'm doing wrong? Right now, all I see is a blank space where the ComboBox should be. I've tried the following things without success that I suspect might be the issue:

- Should my list of `Color`s be in the object itself or my ViewModel? I've tried both, and I've also tried making the property static.
- Adding `DataGridComboBoxColumn.ElementStyle` and `DataGridComboBoxColumn.EditingElementStyle`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work:

```
<DataGridComboBoxColumn Header="Test"
                        SelectedValueBinding="{Binding Color, StringFormat=F3, Mode=TwoWay}" 
                        ItemsSource="{x:Static local:Object.Colors}"/>
```

`local` maps to the namespace where `Object` is defined:

```
xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApp1"
```

Comment: Hmm this is interesting. It seems as if I'm able to get the desired text to appear in the column, but there isn't a combobox there. Is there a difference between SelectedValueBinding and SelectedItemBinding here or is there anything else I can try to get a modifiable value there?

Comment: Nevermind I think I got it! I needed to set ```IsReadOnly = "False"```